# how to load ImageNet when we train a cnn model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I have downloaded the ImageNet and unzip the file. So the images are stored in 1000 subfolders based on category.

how can I load the datasets? read the image one by one?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a preprocessing script that reads all images from this subfolders and integrates it in a unique structure that will be persisted to disk, for example a numpy object written to disk or using pickle.

Comment: thx a lot! there is only 16G ram in my computer. I don't know whether I can read all images without memory error.